is it possible to run a ci/cd pipeline of a project after merge from approved merge request while using merge request predefined variables
I will explain my problem with a scenario to make it clearer.
What I have:

main branch (default, protected): have .gitignore + locked cicd.yml
file
feature branch: copied from main and then added required feature
.gitlab-ci.yml file contains build and deploy jobs for the project (needs merge request predefined variables-- title + description)

The wanted scenario:

dev commits changes to feature branch and request a merge to main needs approval -> .gitlab-ci.yml doesn't run
when request is approved then merged -> run .gitlab-ci.yml in main not feature using $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_* predefined variables (title and description)

 I have tried the follwing workflow rules
rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_APPROVED && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /^v\d+(\.\d+){2}$/ && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION != "" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION =~ $MERGE_REQUEST_DESC_PATTERN && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT_TYPE == "merged_result"

I need to check $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE and $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION so they can't be removed (they are also used to build the image $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE is image tag)
 is it possible to achieve this scenario? if not can you suggest a workaround
thank you in advance

I have found a solution of making the pipeline run twice once for merge requests and the other for the actual merge
1- the pipeline will not run unless the MR/push target is main
2- in merge request process show validation jobs only $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" then check the title and description as required.
3- to reuse merge request values (title and description) as intended, I have changed the settings for commit's messages of merge request to
%{title} # ----> $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE mapped to $CI_COMMIT_TITLE
%{description} # ----> $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION mapped to $CI_COMMIT_DESCRIPTION

this way if the merge request was accepted (merged) a new commit will follow the previous template
4- in push process the build/deploy jobs will use the mapped values to build the image registry/project/image:$CI_COMMIT_TITLE and deploy it, this pipeline will run in main not in merge request


If I understood you correctly you need to run pipeline only when you have merged comething to main branch? If it so there's a rule for a job, that will run in main branch:
    if: '($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^main\/*/) && ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push")'
    when: on_success

Make notice, that actuall action when it's merged is "push". So you need to make sure, that your main branch is protected for force push.
For merge request event it should be:
  if: '($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^main\/*/) && ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event")'
  when: on_success


I did that but what I need is to check merge request (title and description) values then continue the pipeline after merge with the previous values

Doesn't  quite understood about "previous values".  Your pipeline attached to some comit on some branch. If you merge again it would be new pipeline. With newest gitlab version you could cancel previous pipeline after adding new commit to branch. If you need to check title and description, you could just add your rules:  && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /^v\d+(\.\d+){2}$/ && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION != ""

sorry for not being clear, maybe my answer post will clarify the misunderstanding

In my practice it's better to use tags for that. Then you will have to add additional jobs: find a previous tag and increase the last number(infront of all jobs) and place a new tag to current branch(after all). First job is sh script, as a result - env file with a few variables. Second job is also an sh script, that going to gitlab and place tag by itself on current branch.  Both script placed inside a container. For develop branches I personally setup a Gitlab nicknames as tags.
